# copy activities queued for long time

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are migrating the data from Oracle data warehouse to Azure SQL Data Warehouse through copy data activity and the status is showing always in Queue for all the pipelines from the last two weeks. Its almost taking 30 minutes to 45 minutes in queue for 4000 records(Azure IR north central US).

> SUBSCRIPTION ID:2ac8ee00-839a-4148-8460-d5265a560467.

Please let me know what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The queue time you mentioned is pretty high . Can you please try to see how things works when

- Let the source be Oracle DW and let the sink be a blob .Do you see any improvement ? if yes the Synapse is having some issue .
- Get the blob as the source and try to to pump in the data to Synapse , if you see any improvement , Oracle DW is having an issue .
- If there is no improvement something else is going wrong .
- Are all the resource in the same region ?
- Was this thing working before ever ?